# Images not being displayed properly

Tags: matlab, image-processing, color-mapping

I am working with MATLAB R2012b. I am trying to get 7 images to display on one figure but I can get the image that MATLAB to displays to look exactly like the original file. I set the color map to gray in hopes that you make it look the same but no its still different. I have included both the original and what I get from MATLAB so you can see what is happening.

Here is my code:

```
w8 = imread('Winter8','jpg');
subplot(2,4,1), image(w8);
title('Winter8.jpg');
axis('off','image');
colormap('gray');
truesize;
```

And here are the images:

Orirginal:

[image: Winter8Small.jpg Original]

Result from MATLAB:

[image: Winter8Small.jpg results from MATLAB]

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagesc seems to work better than image

> imagesc(w8);
>
> colormap('gray');

Comment: Wow, that worked brilliantly! Thanks. (only two letters, lol)

Answer (score 0):

`imagesc` makes a nicer looking image in your case because you seem interested in using a gray color map as a filter. You can specify a range with `clims`, but you don’t have as much control as with `image`.

If you run `colorbar` on your figure, you’ll see what I’m talking about.

`image` would be better to use in a situation where you want much finer control over your data. For example, if you wanted to plot your data in true color instead of with a colormap, it would be easier to hack that together with the `image` function compared to the `imagesc` function because you wouldn’t be worried about scaling `clims` with a true color image.